# Problems with "sudo apt-get upgrade" (errors in /usr/sbin/update-rc.d)

Tags: apt, upgrade

When trying to do `apt-get upgrade`, I'm getting the following output:

```
# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmysqlclient20 mysql-common
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
25 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 826 kB of archives.
After this operation, 63.5 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [16.8 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libmysqlclient20 amd64 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [809 kB]
Fetched 826 kB in 1s (689 kB/s)           
(Reading database ... 223995 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) over (5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libmysqlclient20_5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) over (5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up udev (229-4ubuntu7) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
    (Do you need to predeclare case?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near "echo "Starting noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "n "Shutting down noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare n?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, near "killproc"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Semicolon seems to be missing at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 466.
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 458, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "stop)
    "
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "
Execution of /usr/sbin/update-rc.d aborted due to compilation errors.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
Setting up grub-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2) ...
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
    (Do you need to predeclare case?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near "echo "Starting noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "n "Shutting down noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare n?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, near "killproc"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Semicolon seems to be missing at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 466.
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 458, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "stop)
    "
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "
Execution of /usr/sbin/update-rc.d aborted due to compilation errors.
dpkg: error processing package grub-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub2-common:
 grub2-common depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc-bin:
 grub-pc-bin depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc:
 grub-pc depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
 grub-pc depends on grub2-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package grub2-common is not configured yet.
 grub-pc depends on grub-pc-bin (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package grub-pc-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up lightdm (1.18.2-0ubuntu2) ...
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
    (Do you need to predeclare case?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near "echo "Starting noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "n "Shutting down noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare n?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, near "killproc"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Semicolon seems to be missing at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 466.
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 458, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "stop)
    "
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "
Execution of /usr/sbin/update-rc.d aborted due to compilation errors.
dpkg: error processing package lightdm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up openssh-server (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1) ...
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
    (Do you need to predeclare case?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near "echo "Starting noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "n "Shutting down noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare n?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, near "killproc"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Semicolon seems to be missing at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 466.
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 458, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "stop)
    "
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "
Execution of /usr/sbin/update-rc.d aborted due to compilation errors.
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ssh:
 ssh depends on openssh-server (>= 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package openssh-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ssh (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up clamav-freshclam (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2) ...
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
    (Do you need to predeclare case?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near "echo "Starting noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "n "Shutting down noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare n?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, near "killproc"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Semicolon seems to be missing at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 466.
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 458, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "stop)
    "
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "
Execution of /usr/sbin/update-rc.d aborted due to compilation errors.
dpkg: error processing package clamav-freshclam (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of clamav:
 clamav depends on clamav-freshclam (>= 0.99+dfsg) | clamav-data; however:
  Package clamav-freshclam is not configured yet.
  Package clamav-data is not installed.
  Package clamav-freshclam which provides clamav-data is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package clamav (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of clamav-daemon:
 clamav-daemon depends on clamav-freshclam (>= 0.99+dfsg) | clamav-data; however:
  Package clamav-freshclam is not configured yet.
  Package clamav-data is not installed.
  Package clamav-freshclam which provides clamav-data is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package clamav-daemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.108ubuntu15.2) ...
Your console font configuration will be updated the next time your system
boots. If you want to update it now, run 'setupcon' from a virtual console.
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
    (Do you need to predeclare case?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near "echo "Starting noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "n "Shutting down noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare n?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, near "killproc"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Semicolon seems to be missing at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 466.
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 458, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "stop)
    "
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "
Execution of /usr/sbin/update-rc.d aborted due to compilation errors.
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup-linux:
 console-setup-linux depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.2); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on console-setup-linux; however:
  Package console-setup-linux is not configured yet.
 console-setup depends on keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.2); however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up cups-browsed (1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) ...
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
    (Do you need to predeclare case?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 457, near "echo "Starting noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near ")
    echo"
    (Missing operator before echo?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "n "Shutting down noip2.""
    (Do you need to predeclare n?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, near "killproc"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
String found where operator expected at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}""
    (Do you need to predeclare echo?)
Semicolon seems to be missing at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 466.
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 455, near "case "$1""
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 458, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 461, near "stop)
    "
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 462, at end of line
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 465, near "echo "
Execution of /usr/sbin/update-rc.d aborted due to compilation errors.
dpkg: error processing package cups-browsed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upower:
 upower depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package upower (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-session-bin:
 gnome-session-bin depends on upower (>= 0.9.0); however:
  Package upower is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-session-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-session:
 gnome-session depends on gnome-session-bin (>= 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.2); however:
  Package gnome-session-bin is not configured yet.
 gnome-session depends on gnome-session-bin (<< 3.19); however:
  Package gnome-session-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-session (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of light-locker:
 light-locker depends on lightdm; however:
  Package lightdm is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package light-locker (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager:
 network-manager depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager-gnome:
 network-manager-gnome depends on network-manager (>= 1.1); however:
  Package network-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-core:
 xserver-xorg-core depends on keyboard-configuration; however:
  Package keyboard-configuration is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-core depends on udev (>= 149); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-intel:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-intel depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-intel (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xubuntu-core:
 xubuntu-core depends on lightdm; however:
  Package lightdm is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xubuntu-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xubuntu-desktop:
 xubuntu-desktop depends on lightdm; however:
  Package lightdm is not configured yet.
 xubuntu-desktop depends on xubuntu-core; however:
  Package xubuntu-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up mysql-common (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 grub-common
 grub2-common
 grub-pc-bin
 grub-pc
 lightdm
 openssh-server
 ssh
 clamav-freshclam
 clamav
 clamav-daemon
 keyboard-configuration
 console-setup-linux
 console-setup
 cups-browsed
 upower
 gnome-session-bin
 gnome-session
 light-locker
 network-manager
 network-manager-gnome
 xserver-xorg-core
 xserver-xorg-video-intel
 xubuntu-core
 xubuntu-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What were you doing before this happened?

Comment: Have you tried ```apt-get -f install``` maybe this will fix the problem with packages that were not properly installed. Also have you touch /usr/sbin/update-rc.d ?

Comment: This is strange. My `update-rc.d` has only 449 lines.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the `update-rc.d` script mentioned in the error messages. It appears that all kinds of junk have been appended to it. The script ought to end with the subroutine definition `sub is_initscripts_installed { ... }` in six lines.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/update-rc.d` looks corrupted on your system. Can you try to reinstall it with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall init-system-helpers`?